# Forward only BIND server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have a unique situation where I provide hosting service with subdomain.mycompany.com to my users. The subdomain can be hosted on any of my geographically distributed servers which has their own name servers configured.

To correctly resolve IP addresses I have created a "forward" only name server which basically acts as a gateway to all other name servers. Makes sense?

Here is my config

```
options {
    allow-query { any; };
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    auth-nxdomain no;    
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    recursion yes;
    forwarders {
            nameserver-loc1.ip;
            nameserver-loc2.ip;
            nameserver-loc3.ip;
            nameserver-loc4.ip;
    };

    forward only;
}
```

My question is - Am I in the right direction (as I am new to BIND server) and how can I secure this configuration to increase security posture.

Comment: Your first paragraph sounds nothing like a unique situation.  Someone has a domain, someone has name servers resolving that domain in multiple locations.  That's common practice.  Are you unaware of what a slave is?  Also, your 'how can I secure this' is far too broad to be answered properly in this format.  What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Its unique because I have no control over the name servers in multiple locations, I can't make them in slave config. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Secure - Since I am making my name server publicly available I am concerned about its security like DNS Amplification attack. To be more precise "Is a forward only nameserver prone to usual DNS attacks or not?"

Comment: the decisive part with DNS attacks would most likely be the `recursion` setting. Setting it to true tends to attract people.

Comment: Maybe: if you just want to serve your own zones, I'ld recommend going with NSD (which won't do the caching or recursion magic BIND does). You can still use bind running some cache - should you need one. Or even unbound.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your setup correctly, it doesn't sound like it will work.

First of all, forwarding in BIND works as a variation of recursion. Ie, it will only be acted upon if the `RD` (Recursion Desired) bit is set in the incoming query.
Forwarding will happen if someone has your nameserver in `resolv.conf` (the OS stub resolver does set `RD`) but when a domain has been delegated to your server and some recursor out there queries your server `RD` is not set.

Secondly, `NXDOMAIN` is a valid response and will not trigger retries, so if the first forwarder that is used answers with `NXDOMAIN` this is what the response to the client will be.
Actual errors, like `SERVFAIL` or lack of a response would cause it to try the next server as well, though.

And as for security, from what I can tell this is largely a non-issue considering that it seems like a fundamentally non-working setup.
However, while your setup allows recursion from absolutely anywhere, which is normally disastrous, it is set to forward only and lists your own presumably authoritative-only nameservers (if they do allow recursion, however, stick to "disastrously bad"), the set of names that you can actually get answers on is limited and I suppose the end result is not that much more problematic than just a normal authoritative server.

Comment: I would agree - `allow-query { any; };` is a slightly strange choice if you were specifically looking to secure your forwarder/resolver. I would probably have started by restricting where queries can come from in a situation where security was a concern.