# Query every forwarding server in BIND

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am using 4 forwarding servers in BIND. like this:

```
forwarders {
        nameserver-loc1.ip;
        nameserver-loc2.ip;
        nameserver-loc3.ip;
        nameserver-loc4.ip;
};

forward only;
```

Problem - any one of the forwarders can have a valid response and others may not. My understanding is that BIND chooses any one forwarder at random and forwards the request. If the request is not found (which is a valid response) BIND does not send that request to any other name-server.

If my understanding is correct, please let me know how can I achieve my desired config or if I have to use any other way.

Answer (score 1):

From [your other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/837184/forward-only-bind-server) I assume that each of the name servers is responsible for a complete subdomain.

In that case, you would just delegate the various subdomains to their respective name servers, just like `example.com` is delegated to other name servers from the `com` TLD.

This way, you basically tell the DNS clients "for `domain1.example.com` ask this other server, not me".

Alternatively (or even combined), you could configure your primary server to act as slave for the various subdomain servers. That way, the primary server will serve the requests with a copy of the zone data from the subdomain servers it gets regularly via a zone transfer.

There are plenty of websites available outlining how to configure BIND for these approaches.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is right in your approach except one catch - for `domain1.example.com` my nameserver forwards the request to one of the 4 forwarders at random (as it doesn't have the zone information) which is obviously not reliable. 

I don't have permission to zone transfer from the parent NS.

Comment: Sorry, but then your approach is broken. That is not how DNS works.

Comment: You were right, this is not how DNS works and there was no workaround. I ended up using a python DNS server and modifying it for my requirement. https://github.com/vikasprogrammer/dnserver

Comment: But, but … BUT you too can do this random selections of DNS forwarders, just not with Bind DNS.  Try KnotDNS random forwarders here: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/kresd-random-dns-forwarding.html